The GET method is not supported for route crea/attività/professionale. Supported methods: PATCH trustproxies error
I'm reporting this problem which only occurs with the Chrome browser while it works correctly on all other browsers. and I don't understand why the complete code is below.
This error occurs only in the chrome browser while with all other browsers everything works as it should. The problem only occurs when I want to save the recorded audio. The error is highlighted in the trustproxies.php file at the code return $next($request). I don't understand why this problem only occurs with Chrome while for example Mozilla everything works normally. I hope someone can help me understand where the problem is, thanks
Route::middleware('auth', 'admin')->group(function () {
    Route::patch('/salva/attivita/specifica', [CreaAttivitàController::class, 'store'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('salva.attività');
    Route::patch('/crea/attività/professionale', [CreaAttivitàController::class, 'indexProfessionale'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('update.manutenzione.professionale');
    Route::post('/salva/attività/professionale', [CreaAttivitàController::class, 'storeProfessionale'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('salva.attività.professionale');
    Route::patch('/modifica/attività/professionale', [CreaAttivitàController::class, 'modificaProfessionale'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('modifica.attività.professionale');
});

<form action="{{ route('salva.attività.professionale') }}" method="POST"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
 @method('POST')
<input type="button" id="recordButton" />
 <input type="file" id="hiddenAudioInput" name="audios[]"
 multiple hidden />
</form>

public function storeProfessionale(Request $request)
    {
        $area = $request->area;
        $qr_linea = $request->qr_linea;
        $linea = Linee::where('qr_code', $qr_linea)->value('nome_linea');
        $qr_blocco = $request->qr_blocco;
        $blocco = BloccoLinee::where('qr_code', $qr_blocco)->value('nome_blocco');
        $qr_macchina = $request->qr_macchina;
        $macchina = $request->macchina;
        $frequenza = "personalizzata";
        $ciclo = $request->ciclo;
        $start = $request->start;
        $durata = $request->durata;
        $stato = "Da fare";
        $step_id_value = $request->step_id;
        $step = $request->step;
        $permessi_1 = $request->checked;
        $permessi = array($permessi_1);
            $attività_id = Attivita::create([
                'area' => $area,
                'linea' => $linea,
                'blocco_linea' => $blocco,
                'macchina' => $macchina,
                'frequenza' => $frequenza,
                'ciclo' => $ciclo,
                'start' => $start,
                'stato' => $stato,
                'qr_code' => $qr_macchina,
                'qr_macchina' => $qr_macchina,
                'qr_blocco' => $qr_blocco,
                'qr_linea' => $qr_linea,
                'durata' => $durata
            ])->id;
            Attivita::where('id', $attività_id)->update(['permessi' => $permessi]);
            $step_id = Step::create([
                'attivita_id' => $attività_id,
                'step_id' => $step_id_value,
                'step' => $step
            ])->id;
            $request->validate([
                'audios.*' => 'nullable|file|mimes:ogg,mp3,m4a,mp4,mpeg,mpga,wav,aac',
            ]);         
            if ($request->hasFile('audios')) {
                foreach ($request->file('audios') as $audio) {
                    $audioName = $audio->hashName();
                    $audio->storeAs('audio', $audioName, 'private');
                    Audio::create([
                        'attivita_id' => $attività_id,
                        'step_id' => $step_id,
                        'audio' => htmlspecialchars($audioName, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
                    ]);
                }
            }
            $notifiche = Aree::sum('attività');
            $item_step = Attivita::with(['step'])
                ->where('id', $attività_id)
                ->first();
            $step_count = Step::where('attivita_id', $attività_id)->get()->last()->step_id + 1;
            $macchina_item = Macchine::where('qr_code', $qr_macchina)->get();
            return $this->indexProfessionale($request)->with(['notifiche' => $notifiche, 'macchina' => $macchina_item, 'data_frequenza' => $start, 'ciclo' => $ciclo, 'step' => $step_count, 'item_step' => $item_step])
                ->withErrors(['msgSuccess' => "Step creato correttamente"]);
    }

let mediaRecorder;
let audioChunks = [];
const recordButton = document.getElementById('recordButton');
const audioGallery = document.getElementById('audioGallery');
recordButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    if (!mediaRecorder) {
        try {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
                audioChunks.push(event.data);
            };
            mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
                const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/webm' });
                const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
                audioChunks = [];
                addAudioToGallery(audioUrl);
            };
            mediaRecorder.start();
            recordButton.classList.add('recording');
            recordButton.textContent = 'Ferma Registrazione';
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Errore durante la registrazione:', error);
            alert('Error: ' + error.message);
        }
    } else {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        recordButton.classList.remove('recording');
        recordButton.textContent = 'Avvia Registrazione';
        mediaRecorder = null;
    }
});
function addAudioToGallery(audioUrl) {
    const audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.controls = true;
    audioElement.src = audioUrl;
    audioGallery.appendChild(audioElement);
}

function addAudioToGallery(audioUrl) {
    const audioItem = document.createElement('div');
    audioItem.classList.add('audio-item');
    const audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.controls = true;
    audioElement.src = audioUrl;
    audioElement.name = "audios[]";
    const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
    removeBtn.classList.add('remove-btn-record');
    const imgDelete = document.createElement('img');
    imgDelete.src = "/css/external/Icone/Delete.svg";
    imgDelete.id = "delete";
    imgDelete.alt = "Rimuovi";
    removeBtn.appendChild(imgDelete);
    removeBtn.onclick = () => {
        audioGallery.removeChild(audioItem);
        // Rimuovi anche il file dall'input nascosto
        removeAudioFromInput(audioUrl);
    };
    audioItem.appendChild(audioElement);
    audioItem.appendChild(removeBtn);
    audioGallery.appendChild(audioItem);
    addAudioToInput(audioUrl);
}

function addAudioToInput(audioUrl) {
    const hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hiddenAudioInput');
    fetch(audioUrl)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok: ' + response.statusText);
        }
        return response.blob();
    })
    .then(blob => {
        const file = new File([blob], 'audio_' + Date.now() + '.wav', { type: 'audio/wav' });
        const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
        for (const file of hiddenInput.files) {
            dataTransfer.items.add(file);
        }
        dataTransfer.items.add(file);
        hiddenInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetch dell\'audio:', error);
    });
}

function removeAudioFromInput(audioUrl) {
    const hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hiddenAudioInput');
    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
    for (const file of hiddenInput.files) {
        if (!file.name.includes(audioUrl)) { // Assicurati di avere un modo per identificare il file
            dataTransfer.items.add(file);
        }
    }
    hiddenInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
}

/**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>|string|null
     */
    protected $proxies;

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $headers =
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR |
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST |
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT |
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO |
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;

    /**
     * Add Content Security Policy headers to accept everything already present in your Laravel app.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->headers->set('Content-Security-Policy', "default-src\'self\'");

        $response->headers->add([
            'Content-Security-Policy' => "default-src\ 'self'; object-src 'self'; base-uri 'self'; report-uri 'self';",
        ]);

        $response->headers->set('Permissions-Policy', "geolocation=()");

        $response->headers->set('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains');

        $response->headers->set('Referrer-Policy', 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin');

        return $response;
    }


You have declared that route as PATCH, but your trying to get data using the GET method, which looks like is the correct.
Also this is so wrong:
Route::patch('/crea/attività/professionale', [CreaAttivitàController::class, 'indexProfessionale'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('update.manutenzione.professionale');

Your calling an indexProfessionale that should be getting a list of professioals but then you name the route like update.. wich matches with a Patch route.

Ok, but the author says that his code works good on FireFox

yes exactly on firefox it works while the thing I noticed on chrome in the network card is that when I record an audio to call the js function that records a get request starts, is it possible that it is the one causing the conflict on chrome ?
